# How to compile Linux Mint Cinnamon disc image?

Tags: linux, linux-mint, meson-build, cinnamon

As I understand, [Cinnamon repository](https://github.com/linuxmint/cinnamon) uses Meson as a build system. I'm using WSL to build it from sources, in the hope that I will get a bootable disc image (like an ISO). I had to manually install some requirements as needed when running `meson build` at the root of the repository. The Cinnamon repository doesn't have any guide on how to build the repository.

When I run `meson build`, right now I'm stuck with the dependency `cjs-1.0`. I've ran `sudo apt install cjs`. I've googled and nothing unfortunately. What else can I consider?

```
The Meson build system
Version: 0.53.2
Source dir: /home/matheus/cinnamon
Build dir: /home/matheus/cinnamon/build
Build type: native build
Project name: Cinnamon
Project version: 5.4.11
C compiler for the host machine: cc (gcc 9.4.0 "cc (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.1) 9.4.0")
C linker for the host machine: cc ld.bfd 2.34
Host machine cpu family: x86_64
Host machine cpu: x86_64
Found pkg-config: /usr/bin/pkg-config (0.29.1)
Run-time dependency dbus-1 found: YES 1.12.16
Found CMake: /usr/bin/cmake (3.16.3)
Run-time dependency cjs-1.0 found: NO (tried pkgconfig and cmake)

meson.build:24:0: ERROR: Dependency "cjs-1.0" not found, tried pkgconfig and cmake
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be available after installing libcjs-dev package:

```
$ sudo apt install libcjs-dev
...
$ pkg-config --list-all | grep cjs
cjs-1.0                             cjs-1.0 - Cinnamon JS bindings for GObjects
```

Comment: Unfortunately it's not yet there after installing `libcjs-dev`. Thanks though. I did `$ pkg-config --list-all | grep cjs` and it prints `cjs-1.0` in red. More specifically I got `Dependency cjs-1.0 found: NO found 4.4.0 but need: '>= 4.8.0'`

Comment: @MatheusDiasdeSouza ok, which Linux Mint version you are running ?

Comment: @MatheusDiasdeSouza it looks you have focal add need backport from impish https://packages.ubuntu.com/impish/libcjs-dev

Comment: I'm using Windows Subsystem for Linux for the build process. I've just found a blog post somewhere: https://blog.desdelinux.net/en/como-compilar-e-instalar-la-ultima-version-de-cinnamon/ Not sure if I should continue trying Meson and install libcjs or follow this blog.

Comment: What do you have in /etc/apt/sources.list ? try adding backport to lines with  "deb http://packages.linuxmint.com ... " but it looks you are using very old linux mint version and guide is very old! it refers maya which is 10 years old

Comment: @MatheusDiasdeSouza after updating source list -> sudo apt update; sudo apt-get install --only-upgrade libcjs-dev

Comment: With this command I got `libcjs-dev is already the newest version (4.4.0-4).`. About sources.list, I uncommented `deb-src` lines and even copy-pasted from the blogpost. Now, the only issue I've got following the blogpost is that when I run `cd muffin && dpkg-buildpackage` I get `Unmet build dependencies: cinnamon-desktop-data (>= 5.3.0)`, but when I run `sudo apt install cinnamon-desktop-data` it says `cinnamon-desktop-data is already the newest version (4.4.1-3).`. Is that an issue with WSL maybe?

Comment: @MatheusDiasdeSouza have no experience with WSL at all, as I see you need to install add to sources.list backports from https://packages.ubuntu.com/impish/libcjs-dev (21.10) https://askubuntu.com/questions/25717/how-do-i-enable-the-backports-repository

Comment: Now I understand what you mean by backports, this was useful. For `cinnamon-desktop-data` I need to add `kinetic` to my `deb` lines, and it seems like `apt update` worked fine. However I'm unable to install `cinnamon-desktop-data` as I get breaks: `The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 cinnamon-desktop-data : Breaks: cinnamon-settings-daemon (< 5.4) but 4.4.0-3 is to be installed`, `gir1.2-cvc-1.0 : Breaks: cinnamon-settings-daemon (< 5.4) but 4.4.0-3 is to be installed`, `libcvc0 : Breaks: cinnamon-settings-daemon (< 5.4) but 4.4.0-3 is to be installed`.

Comment: I've reinstalled `cinnamon-settings-daemon` after `kinetic` backport and it worked!

Comment: About the `cjs` package I think I'm gonna try it later.